# Unity - Odd distortion on default material cube

Tags: unity

Does anyone know what causes this strange effect that looks like ripples? This is simply the default material on a cube and should be perfectly smooth. (Clear example at top right of image)

[image]

Another example:

[image]

Comment: This looks like a Z-fighting artifact. Any chance you might have two coplanar faces here? Does it change at all as you toggle or move lights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty much like shadowing artifacts which are known as [*shadow acne*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908835/what-causes-shadow-acne). In your scene, select the light source in the Inspector. Try setting the **Bias** and **Normal Bias** properties for better results.

Depending on your scene you'll be able to find a sweet spot for those values. It really depends on many details like at which angle the light hits the surface or how big your meshes are, the camera distance etc.

There's no real 'golden rule', just figure out which values work best in your case.

Also, check out the [official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ShadowOverview.html). You'll find an in-depth explanation on shadows in general but also on this specific issue.

[image: Light properties]